# Best way to iterate this json code using PHP

Tags: php

I have this json code:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John",
         "id": "11"
      },
      {
         "name": "Max",
         "id": "22"
      },
      {
         "name": "Martin",
         "id": "33"
      },
      {
         "name": "Adrian",
         "id": "44"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I need to print all names and ids in this way:

```
John 11
Max 22
Martin 33
Adrian 44
```

What is the simplest way to do that ?

Comment: http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%7B%0D%0A+++%22data%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A++++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%22name%22%3A+%22John%22%2C%0D%0A+++++++++%22id%22%3A+%2211%22%0D%0A++++++%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%22name%22%3A+%22Max%22%2C%0D%0A+++++++++%22id%22%3A+%2222%22%0D%0A++++++%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%22name%22%3A+%22Martin%22%2C%0D%0A+++++++++%22id%22%3A+%2233%22%0D%0A++++++%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%22name%22%3A+%22Adrian%22%2C%0D%0A+++++++++%22id%22%3A+%2244%22%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A+++%5D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($string, true); // true to retrieve an associative array
foreach($arr['data'] as $sub) {
  echo $sub['name'],' ',$sub['id'],PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
John 11
Max 22
Martin 33
Adrian 44
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a='{ "data": [ { "name": "John", "id": "11" }, { "name": "Max", "id": "22" }, { "name": "Martin", "id": "33" }, { "name": "Adrian", "id": "44" } ] }';
$b=json_decode($a);
$data=$b->{'data'};
foreach($data as $item) {
  print $item->{'name'}.' '.$item->{'id'}."\n";
}

?>
```

And for extra points, the Javascript version:

```
objectValueList=function(x) {
  var tags=[];
  for (i in x) {
    if(x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      tags.push(x[i]);
    }
  }
  return tags;
}


var a='{ "data": [ { "name": "John", "id": "11" }, { "name": "Max", "id": "22" }, { "name": "Martin", "id": "33" }, { "name": "Adrian", "id": "44" } ] }';
var b=JSON.parse(a);
var data=objectValueList(b.data);
for (x in data) {
  console.log(data[x].name+" "+data[x].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` .

```
$data=json_decode($string);

foreach($data as $person){
    foreach($person as $key=>$val){
        foreach($val as $tuple)
            echo $tuple." ";
        echo "\r\n"; 
        }
    }   
}
```